# My class has some unknown error that when ran, the JFrame does not respond after inputting a value

Tags: java, eclipse

I am attempting to create a probability generator based on the game of Craps to see the various probabilities.

My CrapsGame program seems to not work when doing probability of winning based off on my logical statements and frankly, I do not know what exactly is the problem as the Console does not mention any when ran.

```
public class CrapsGame
{
  private int point = 0;

  /**
   *  Calculates the result of the next dice roll in the Craps game.
   *  The parameter total is the sum of dots on two dice.
   *  point is set to the saved total, if the game continues,
   *  or 0, if the game has ended.
   *  Returns 1 if player won, -1 if player lost,
   *  0 if player continues rolling.
   */
  public int processRoll(int total)
  {
    int result = 0;
    if (point == 0){
      if (total == 7 || total == 11){
        result = 1;
      }else if (total == 2 || total == 3 || total == 12){
        result = -1;
      }else{
       point = total;
       result = 0;
      }
       }else{
          if (total == point){
             point = 0;
             result = 1;
         }else if (total == 7){
           point = 0;
            result = -1;
      }else{
        result = 0;
      }

    }
    return result;
    }
```

When I attempt to run the program only returns a 0% win rate, no matter the amount of games.

Comment: How are you using your method? Can you show the rest of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I append

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.err.println(new CrapsGame().processRoll(7));
    }
}
```

then it prints

```
1
```

So clearly the problem is not (entirely) within the code presented.

**Edit:** Or are you referring to `point`?

```
    CrapsGame game = new CrapsGame();
    game.processRoll(4);
    System.err.println(game.point);
```

Gives:

```
4
```

I'm not sure where `JFrame` comes into this or the eclipse tag.

Comment: I don't the current code on me at the moment since its on a school computer, but basically the processRoll method will be put into an object called Die1 and Die2. Besides that, the processRoll method is put into a test class where its just the main purpose is to test the probability on through JFrame. This is where the problem comes in, unknown to me the JFrame crashes if I put a value into, it doesn't close nor report back an error, just freezes after I press enter on a normal, integer value.